# Copy constructor for object with vector as member variable

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor, member

I have a class `A` with a `vector<Object> object_list_` as a member variable.

I know that if I had a vector of pointers I would have needed to write a specific copy constructor to achieve a deep copy. However, in this case, as I don't have pointers, when copying an object of type `A`, the default copy constructor will automatically also call the copy constructors of `Object` or each element in `object_list_` or do I have to write my own copy constructor to do that?

Comment: In general you should rely on the default copy constructor as much as possible, and write your classes such that it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of your C++ book?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default copy constructor for your class will call the default copy constructor for each member, in the order they're declared in the class.  One rule of thumb is that if you don't need a special destructor, then you don't need to change the copy constructor, copy assignment, move constructor, or move assignment either. (Though deleting them may still make sense, depending on the class).

A vector's copy constructor will make a copy of its elements, using their copy constructors.  If those are *pointers*, it will copy *the pointers*, which means they'll point at the same data as the origonal vector.  99% of the time this is what you want. Though very rarely you may want to replace your class' copy constructor to make the vector do something else.

It sounds like you don't need to make a copy constructor in your case.

Comment: So it will automatically iterate through the vector and call the relative default copy constructor, am I right?

Comment: @Gabrielecswoosh: Yes, the vector will call the copy constructor for each element it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Copy constructors of member variables are called all the way down. So if a default one was generated (and it would be in this case) then it gets called.