# Copying objects with all elements in C++! (Constructors and Assignment, best practice?)

Tags: c++, oop, vector, copy-constructor, default-copy-constructor

I rummaged through SO and learned a lot regarding default constructors, copy constructors, objects assignment, smart pointers, shallow/deep copy and their relationships with dynamic memory allocation (e.g. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902751/how-to-clone-object-in-c-or-is-there-another-solution), [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262732/copy-constructor-for-object-with-vector-fo-object-as-member-variable), [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368258/the-copy-constructor-and-assignment-operator) and ...). However, I'm still fuzzy on drawing a conclusion on what the best practice is to handle copying objects elements such as vectors (or list).

I learnt STL vector, in particular, handles this by its default copy constructor and best practice in this case is to not manage resources yourself. But it seems I'm understanding something wrong.

My effort before asking: I was also able to resolve this with passing the objects by reference but I ended of having too many deference operators (i.e. **).

What's the best practice here for simple small objects such as the one in the following code? Elements in vectors are not being copied properly. (I'd not be surprised if I'm doing extremely simple mistake here. Also, not using raw/shared/smart pointers is preferred if possible).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
    int id;
    A(int id_):id(id_){}
    vector<A> childs;
};

int main()
{
    A a0(0), a1(1);

    a0.childs={a1}; //node0.childs.push_back(node1);
    a1.childs={a0}; //node1.childs.push_back(node0);

    cout << a0.childs.size() << endl; // 1
    cout << a1.childs.size() << endl; // 1
    cout << a0.childs[0].childs.size() << endl; // expecting 1 but 0
    //Probably since they're not pointing to the same address of memory
    //I was hoping vector handle this by itself (was told best practice in this case is to not manage resources yourself)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @SamVarshavchik So true. I tried to narrow my question down to STL containers, hoping to get an advice.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the "this" is that you're trying to resolve. Everything is being copied properly – I suspect that you're expecting some kind of reference semantics. Get a good introductory book and try not to learn everything at once.

Comment: @molbdnilo I want to copy STL containers content, as an element of objects, when I copy them. Vector, in particular.

Comment: Why were you expecting `a0.childs[0].childs` to have a size of 1? It might be good to draw on what you have learned about copy constructors and identify each line where an `A` is copied. So then, how many different `A` objects do you have?

Comment: @ChrisDrew Because it's initially zero but when I added `a0`, as a child, to `a1`. I was expecting to see this effect through `a0.childs[0].childs.size()` after doing this: `a1.childs={a0}`.

Comment: @DamoreSu but you are not really "adding `a1`, as a child, to `a0`" are you. You are adding a *copy* of `a1`, as a child, to `a0`. It is best not to think of it as `a1` anymore. It is a completely separate, unnamed `A` object that is owned by `a0`.

Comment: @DamoreSu You *are* copying the contents. If you didn't copy, you would see the behaviour you're expecting. (If you're coming from some other language - Java/C#/JavaScript/Python/... - there are many things you need to unlearn.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve but if the objective is learning, then I strongly recommend you understand why, what you are expecting to happen, isn't happening. Before you move on to finding a "workaround" to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

To better understand, it might help to write simplified code that demonstrates the same behavior. What you have written is more-or-less equivalent to:

```
struct A {
    int childCount = 0;
};

int main() {
    A a1;
    std::vector<A> vecA{a1};
    a1.childCount = 1;
    std::cout << vecA[0].childCount<< "\n"; // What do you expect here?
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
A a1;
A copyOfA1 = a1;
a1.childCount= 1;
std::cout << copyOfA1.childCount << "\n"; // What do you expect here?
```

which is equivalent to:

```
int a1 = 0;
int copyOfA1 = a1;
a1 = 1;
std::cout << copyOfA1 << "\n";  // What about here?
```

`a0` holds a separate *copy* of `a1` not a reference to `a1` so if you make a change to the original `a1`, the copy of `a1` held in `a0` does not change.

**EDIT**: 
As for how to achieve what you want to achieve. I'm assuming that `A` should not own its children. You want it to contain non-owning references to the `A`s that are held elsewhere. Unfortunately, a `std::vector` cannot hold a C++ reference. The `std::vector` could hold a raw pointer but you specifically asked to not use raw pointers.

An alternative, is a [`std::reference_wrapper<A>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) which is something that behaves a bit like a C++ reference but is assignable so that it can be used in a `std::vector`. You could hide the `std::reference_wrapper` by providing a member function to get access to a child by index:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct A {
    int id;
    A(int id_):id(id_){}
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<A>> childs;
    A& at(size_t index) { return childs[index]; }
};

int main()
{
    A a0(0), a1(1);

    a0.childs={a1};
    a1.childs={a0};

    std::cout << a0.childs.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << a1.childs.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << a0.at(0).childs.size() << "\n";
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JvtMbEWX6TxA8Jxn).

But to be clear, `std::reference_wrapper` is basically just a wrapper around a raw pointer, it is up to you to ensure that object it is pointing to is still alive.

**Edit2**: As requested, here is a version that uses a vector of raw pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    int id;
    A(int id_):id(id_){}
    std::vector<A*> childs;
    A& at(size_t index) { return *childs[index]; }
};

int main()
{
    A a0(0), a1(1);

    a0.childs={&a1};
    a1.childs={&a0};

    std::cout << a0.childs.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << a1.childs.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << a0.at(0).childs.size() << "\n";
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tqM8cVDpBUGNDnQg).

Note that you have to take the address of `a1` using `&` when initializing the vector.

Comment: This level of understanding is amazing. You earned my respect, sir. I loved the surgery you did on my poorly explained question. I understood your workaround, especially now I know where the problem is coming from with your simple yet brilliant example. So, if not wrong, can I now conclude that the correct way to handle such cases is to use `pointers` or `references`? (perhaps using `vector<A>* childs` or `vector<A*> childs`). Can you please shed more lights by adding code using raw pointers too? (if it's the right way to go)

Comment: My confusion originated from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686973/c-copy-constructor-vs-overloaded-assignment-vs-constructor-best-practices) where it says "best practice in copying objects with vectors is to not manage resources yourself."

Comment: I just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27463966/10538564)... seems very relevant. Actually I'm trying to build almost the same kind of reusable graph-theory code for my own practice purposes.

Comment: @DamoreSu I've provided a version that uses `vector<A*>`.

Comment: I see that. Thank you sir. But is this the best way to go? Please go ahead and update your code without any restriction if there is a better way to go (i.e. any types of pointers if needed, e.g. `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`). I greatly appreciate your contribution and will continue educate myself.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460377/why-is-using-vector-of-pointers-considered-bad/27463966#27463966) has made me scratch my head... :/

Comment: When I revisited your answer, I realized that this is what I did initially by passing object by references (and dereferencing them in your `at()`). Sorry for too many questions, I just fully digested your answer. So, reference is the way to go? or there is a better way....? Thanks a ton.

Comment: @DamoreSu I quite like using `std::reference_wrapper` but its use is not that common and the difference between that and a raw pointer is probably just a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

```
a0.childs={a1}; //a1.childs is empty here, so a0.childs will be empty too
a1.childs={a0}; //a0.childs contains one element here and so will a1.childs
```

So

```
 cout << a0.childs[0].childs.size() << endl; // This size will be 0
```

But

```
cout << a1.childs[0].childs.size() << endl; // This will contain one element and the output shows the same.
```

Output:

```
a.exe
a0.childs.size():1
a1.childs.size():1
a0.childs[0].childs.size():0
a1.childs[0].childs.size():1
```

Comment: Yes. I conveyed myself wrong. What is the right solid way to handle it? (liek best practice). Can you add your code please (not the workaround tho)

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to do here. You can fill in the elements of a0 and a1 and use std::swap to exchange the contents.

Comment: I was expecting to see the effect of `a1.childs={a0}` through `a0.childs[0].childs.size()`.

Comment: This will not happen because the assignments involve copies of the objects and not the objects themselves. Changing the object AFTER the assignment will not affect what it has been assigned to.